# How can I include in my program that the integers entered must be between 0 and 100?

Tags: java

The exercise asked me to calculate the average, maximum, and minimum. My code fulfills that purpose, however I need to include somewhere in my code that the exam grades entered by the user MUST be between 0 and 100. What is the best way to include this?
Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class hw 
{
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    int maxGrade = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int minGrade = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int count=0;
    int total=0;
    final int SENTINEL = -1;
    int score;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);
    System.out.println( "To calculate the class average, enter each test   
    score.");
    System.out.println( "When you are finished, enter a -1.");

    System.out.print( "Enter the first test score > ");
    score = scan.nextInt();


    while (score != SENTINEL )
    {
        total += score;
        count ++;
        if( score > maxGrade)
            maxGrade = score;
        if( score < minGrade)
            minGrade = score;

        System.out.print("Enter the next test score > ");
        score = scan.nextInt();
    }
    if (count != 0)
    {
        DecimalFormat oneDecimalPlace = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
        System.out.println( "\nThe class average is " 
                + oneDecimalPlace.format( (double) (total) / count )); 
        System.out.println( "The minimum value is " + minGrade);
        System.out.println( "The maximum value is " + maxGrade);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("\nNo grades were entered");



    }

    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where(&how) do you prevent processing the `SENTINEL`? That would seem an appropriate neighbourhood to enforce restrictions on input values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a nested loop that will stop executing once the user has met the criteria. Something like this:

```
while (score < 0 || score > 100) 
 {
   System.out.println("please enter a number between 0 and 100.");

        while(!scan.hasNextInt())
        {
             scan.next();
        }
      score = scan.nextInt();
  }
```

Note that this code has not been tested, this is just an idea of what it should look like.